# why spines doesn't work with plot() but works with subplot() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I use plot() function to draw plot in matplotlib.

plot().spines doesn't show me the spines

but subplot().spines gives output

Why don't they return same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't return the same output. In fact, `pyplot.plot` is a plotting function which returns a sequence of `Line2D` objects, while `pyplot.subplot` is a gridding function which returns a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object.

[image]

While the `AxesSubplot` has `spines` (as one can imaginge from the image), the `Line2D` does not have any spines (it's a simple line, what would spines be for it?).